# DLL GRAFICADOR(CHART) CAMBIAR SU POSICION O DIRECCION? C#

Tags: c#

En mi proyecto de Visual Studio aplique un DLL Graficador que funciona para todos los casos estilo YvsX, pero no posee los labels o variables que me indican que cosa va contra que (Valor de Y y X) , yo quisiera implementar esos textos a un lado del graficador generado, pero el problema que tengo es que en C# solo se puede aplicar de forma horizontal los labels , hay alguna forma de cambiar esta posición y ponerla de una forma vertical(90 grados), para que se asemeje mas a una grafica normal.

el ejemplo que adjunto , es(pulgadasxmarca)en este caso, como podria hacer que el label de pulgadas que seria el Eje Y me quede de forma vertical o en 90 grados como se suele hacer al dibujar una grafica

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

En el componente chart de windows forms ese tipo de gráfico que describes se identifica con el tipo stackedBar, pero, si has utilizado un componente de terceros, deberás informarte sobre como obtener esta vista en dicho componente.

Ejemplo de tipo de serie horizontal en windowsForms:

```
chart1.Series["LG"].ChartType = SeriesChartType.StackedBar;
chart1.Series["SAMSUNG"].ChartType = SeriesChartType.StackedBar;
```